# Why does including a header cause a "use of auto before deduction of auto" error?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, header-files, auto

I've taken the project I'm working on and shortened it to three brief files that replicate what's happening. I'm working with the Code::Blocks IDE using g++ under the 2011 standard.

The files are `main.cpp`, `thing.cpp` and `thing.h`. The header (`.h`) has declarations and the source (`.cpp`) has implementations. The `thing` files define a class `Thing` with a template parameter `T`. All `Thing` does is hold an object of type `T` (it basically does nothing).

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "thing.h"

int main(){
    Thing<int> a(9);
    Thing<double> b(3.2);
    auto c = a + b;
    c.display();

    return 0;
}
```

`thing.h`:

```
#ifndef THING_H
#define THING_H

template<typename T>
class Thing{
private:
    T content;
public:
    Thing(const T& content);
    ~Thing(){};

    T get_content() const;

    void display();
};

template<typename S, typename T>
auto operator+(const Thing<S>& s, const Thing<T>& t);

#endif // THING_H
```

`thing.cpp`:

```
#include "thing.h"
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
Thing<T>::Thing(const T& content)
:content(content){}

template<typename T>
void Thing<T>::display(){
    std::cout << content << '\n';
}

template<typename T>
T Thing<T>::get_content() const {
    return content;
}

template<typename S, typename T>
auto operator+(const Thing<S>& s, const Thing<T>& t){
    S s_content = s.get_content();
    T t_content = t.get_content();
    Thing<typename std::common_type<S, T>::type> sum = s_content + t_content;
    return sum;
}
```

Here's the strange behavior: the code will compile or not depending on the line `#include "thing.h"`. Using `thing.h` here will not compile, causing an error:

```
error: use of 'auto operator+(const Thing<S>&, const Thing<T>&) [with S = int; T = double]' before deduction of 'auto'
error: invalid use of 'auto'
```

Changing this line to `#include "thing.cpp"` allows the code to compile without problems and functions as intended (it outputs `12.2` to the console).

My question is: *What is the compiler doing differently in the two cases? How can I change the code to eliminate this error when `includ`ing the header?*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably also ask yourself [why you're not implementing your templates in a header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) in the first place? There is no way a caller can possibly deduce the `auto` given only `auto operator+(const Thing<S>& s, const Thing<T>& t);` to work with. It needs the code.

Comment: @WhozCraig Why does the caller only have access to the header and not the implementation in the source file? In fact, how does a caller access the source in other situations? My impression was that when the function is called, the compiler will substitute in the implementation, in which the auto return type can be deduced.

Comment: Compiler can't do that because it needs the template definition at hand when you're about to use it. Main is a translation unit, Thing is another one, and the template class definition of `Thing` doesn't exist in main TU.

Comment: @StoryTeller: No, that is not the cause. Please be more careful with your dupehammer.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi I think I understand the problem. I was under the impression that the `auto` deduction was causing the problem, whereas it's really the template shenanigans. Removing the line `auto c = a + b;` causes new, different errors (`undefined reference to Thing<int>::Thing(etc...)`). I thought the `auto` was to blame because these new errors did not show up when it was included, and the build process will usually spit out a list of *all* the errors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Deduced return types were introduced in C++14.**

Coliru [reproduces your problem in C++11 mode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2646ee938dd1ded2), but [shows the code working in C++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae7eafaec60880a5).

And, of course, although this wasn't the immediate cause of your problem, [it *is* likely that you will have to move your template definitions into the/a header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Oh, and here's the *minimal* testcase you should have been testing with:

```
template <typename T>
auto foo(T a)
{
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    foo(42);
}
```

Comment: The code worked for the OP, by their own admission, when `thing.cpp` was included **instead** of `thing.h`. So it's not a C++11 vs C++14 issue. It is a template being defined not inside a header issue. Which makes only the link in your answer relevant.